# How to choose the stock exchange to trade a stock?

Tags: equities, nasdaq, nyse

Let's take an example : Hewlett Packard. The company is listed on both Nasdaq and Nyse. Correct me if I am wrong but as we can trade it on 2 different stock exchanges the price of the stock may diverge slightly between them. Therefore I don't understand why my broker proposes HP only on Nyse and not Nasdaq. It seem to be the case everywhere : for instance, Google finance exposes HP only on Nyse.

Comment: Under the SEC's regulation NMS, all brokers must provide access to the NBBO (National Best Bid or Offer) whatever exchange(s) trade the stock. Therefore the broker has software that can route your order to multiple exchanges and determines the best one dynamically when your order is processed.